# Javascript: Is there a scenario where one would prefer to declare an object property using prototype?

Tags: javascript

I've just started to learn Javascript.

As per my understanding so far, you can declare class/static variables in two ways. The 1st way:

```
    Blog.prototype.signature = "By Blogger-Name";
```

And the 2nd way:

```
    Blog.signature = "By Blogger-Name";
```

By using the first method, the variable signature is available to all instances of Blog.

However, a variable that remains the same value for all instances of a class should really not be an instance variable. As I see it, class/static variables should be declared using the second method only.

Hence, my question is, is there a scenario where one would be required/forced to declare variables the first way? Or is my understanding of all of this lacking in any way? Please let me know.

EDIT: In what instances is the first method preferred and, similarly, in what instances is the second method preferred?

EDIT 2: So I've learnt that the first method actually adds instance properties with a default value. This can also be achieved by setting a default value in the constructor itself. So when would adding a property this way (i.e. using prototype) be preferred?

Comment: Variable on the prototype would be within the scope of a newly created object instance and could be different for each instance. Without the prototype it become a static property of the object instead of a dynamic one. http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance

Comment: @gillesc but you could just declare instance variables using this inside the constructor. my question is this: when you would **have** to declare a property using protoype?

Comment: Yes you can and you could for methods too but that would impact performance as you will be declaring the property or method each time the constructor is run. Attaching it to the prototype avoid that. It also allows you to have a much cleaner constructor and generally gives you a lot more flexibility to create classes which can extend others and so on.

Comment: And I know it doesn't answer your question, this is why I posted it as a comment. Not sure anything forces you, there is many ways to make a property available on a object. You could add the property to the instance object too, it doesn't need to be on the prototype object or even the class itself. It's more about picking the right one for the job.

Comment: @gillesc My bad, the question should have been asking about which method is preferred when. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence, my question is, is there a scenario where one would be required/forced to declare variables the first way?

The only thing that comes to mind would be if you needed to allow for code using an object created via `new Blog` to access the property without knowing the constructor function's name. E.g.:

```
function useABlogInstance(blog) {
    // Here, assume I don't know that `blog` was created via `new Blog`
    console.log(blog.signature);
}
```

Although a canny user *could* do

```
console.log(blog.constructor.signature);
```

to access `Blog.signature` (assuming you maintain the `constructor` backlink), that wouldn't be very clean. :-)

---

It's important to note that a property on `Blog.prototype` **isn't** a "class" or "static" property, it's an instance property (on the `Blog.prototype` object). While it's true that **reading** that property from an object created via `new Blog` will find it on the prototype (if the instance doesn't have its own `signature` property), the results of **writing** to the property are very, very different. Consider:

```js
function A() {}
A.prototype.prop = "prototype prop";
var a1 = new A();
var a2 = new A();
snippet.log(a1.prop); // "prototype prop"
snippet.log(a2.prop); // "prototype prop"
a1.prop = "updated";
snippet.log(a1.prop); // "updated" -- because `a1` has its own `prop` property
                      // now and no longer uses the prototype's
snippet.log(a2.prop); // "prototype prop"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Contrast that with:

```js
function B() {}
B.prop = "B prop";
var b1 = new B();
var b2 = new B();
snippet.log(b1.constructor.prop); // "B prop"
snippet.log(b2.constructor.prop); // "B prop"
snippet.log(B.prop);              // "B prop"
b1.constructor.prop = "updated";
snippet.log(b1.constructor.prop); // "updated"
snippet.log(b2.constructor.prop); // "updated"
snippet.log(B.prop);              // "updated"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

For "class"-wide information, I would always use `Blog.signature`, not `Blog.prototype.signature`. I'd use `Blog.prototype.signature` for instance-specific *default* properties where the values are primitives or functions (but not non-function objects or arrays, I'd set those up in the constructor function).

---

Side note: You're not declaring a variable in either of your code snippets. You're adding a property to an object. In the first snippet, you're adding the property to the object that will get assigned as the prototype of objects created via `new Blog`. In the second case, you're adding a property to the `Blog` object (functions are objects). Neither is a variable, in both cases it's a property.

Comment: @t-j-crowder Thanks for letting me know about the difference between adding a property and declaring variables. Also, I've edited the question to ask when which method is preferred. Do you have anything to add? :)

Comment: @rickyspanish: Amusingly, I just added this to the answer when discussing the difference between those two ways of doing it: *"For "class"-wide information, I would always use `Blog.signature`, not `Blog.prototype.signature`."* :-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder So what I've inferred is from your examples is that add a property through prototype essentially makes it an instance property. Right? But we can add instance properties using this inside the constructor. When would you prefer to use prototype to add instance properties?

Comment: @rickyspanish: Mostly when those properties refer to functions, but I've been known to do it with default values as well, particularly any time I don't think the values will be overridden much.

Comment: @rickyspanish Make sure those default values are immutable or de referenced when you change them for a particular instance. For example a default array of accessories of a Car. When you have an instance and push to its accessories it will mutate that for all Car instances: like specialCar.accessories. push("special") is not a good idea when accessories came from Car.prototype but specialCar.accessories=[] is save

Answer (score 1):

There are no *class variables* in Javascript. Actually, there are no *classes* altogether in Javascript. Thinking in terms of classes and static variables (are you a Java dev?) won't let you know what's going on. Even if the concept of *"a class"* is independent of the programming language to some degree, it is important to understand that it's not a fundamental programming construct - and in fact there are languages without classes, like Javascript.

Javascript is a very simple language: it has functions and dictionaries, and has the syntax to combine both and support programming the object-oriented way. Take this example:

```
var johnSnow = { first: "John", last: "Snow" };

function fullName(character) {
  return character.first + " " + character.last;
}

console.log(fullName(johnSnow));
```

And now the OO version:

```
var Character = function(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
}

Character.prototype.fullName = function() {
  return this.first + " " + this.last;
}

console.log(new Character("John", "Snow").fullName());
```

Finally we can answer your question: when should you set a property on a constructor and when you should use an instance?

- **Set the property on the instance** when they should not be shared with other instances (obviously). You recognize these properties because often are used in instance methods and read with `this.$name`
- **Set the property on the constructor... never!** Properties set on constructors are simply global variables. So just use global variables, possibly namespacing them (but obviously you'll need a global at some point!)

Comment: I've been used to Java way of thinking for so long now, it's getting a little difficult to wrap my head around Javascript OOP. :) Does setting a property on an object's prototype make an instance variable or a static one?

Comment: Improper but... instance. It's like an instance field with a default value. But I don't like it: when you need a default set it explicitely in the constructor

Comment: Okay, now I seem to understand... If you don't mind me asking, when would one actually prefer declaring 'instance' properties this way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it all depends on how you want to access the signature variable.
If you want an easy access to it from a Blog instance, use the `prototype` versions. Then you can do:

```
var blog = new Blog;
console.log(blog.signature);
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use `Blog.signature` or `blog.constructor.signature`.

I wouldn't worry about making `signature` an `instance variable` when you put it in the prototype because that's not what you're doing.

`Blog.prototype` doesn't get copied around -- it's not something every instance would have its own private copy of. It's a shared object that `blog` objects (=objects created with `new Blog`) will have set as their `__proto__` (=`Object.getPrototypeOf(blog)`). `__proto__` will be used to search for properties (that includes functions) that are not direct attributes of the instance.

A `__proto__` can be overriden by setting an actual instance variable:

```
var Blog = function () {};
Blog.prototype.signature = "Original sig";
var blog = new Blog();
blog.signature === "Original sig" 
//^looked up in Blog.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(blog) === blog.__proto__
blog.signature = "New sig" 
//^set as an instance property
blog.signature === "New sig"
Blog.prototype.signature !== "New sig" //actual instance properties override prototype properties, but they don't over-write them 
var blog2 = new Blog()
blog2.signature === "Original sig"
```

A classical object-oriented programming language such as C++/Java does a very similar thing, actually. Objects in C++/Java have properties and methods, and methods behave as if they were function pointer properties of instances, but they're not. Methods don't add any size to instances. They're all looked up in a shared place--your class's prototype if you will. The difference is, that in C++/Java the link doesn't exist at runtime (it's maintained by the compiler) and is only for methods. In JavaScript, each object has a real link to a class-shared lookup place (the object's constructor's `prototype` attribute), the link is accessible via either the objet's `__proto__` attribute or more standardly via what you get with `Object.getPrototypeOf(someobject)`, and it's not only for methods (like in C++/Java) but for properties as well.

Comment: This is so confusing, because the first answer here says that adding properties to an object's prototype makes them instance properties. Now you're saying that it's the opposite.

Comment: It IS the opposite. What's in `Blog.prototype.signature` might be accessible (for reading) via `blog.signature`, but until you write to `blog.signature`, it's more akin to a static class variable in that that until modified, `blog.signature` doesn't take up any additional space in `blog` like a real instance variable would.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between `foo1 = {}` and `foo2 = new Bar` is the fact that `foo1.__proto__ == Object.prototype`, whereas `foo2.__proto__ == Bar.prototype`. In JavaScript there are no classes and no instances, only plan objects.

Now, if you set `Bar.prototype.property = "value"`, then looking up `foo2.property` first checks, whether `foo2` has its own property called `property`. If it does not, it continues with `foo2.__proto__` until it finds an object that does have an own property called `property` or until it gets to an object, whose `__proto__` is `null` (usually `Object.prototype`).

It should now be obvious that by declaring `Bar.prototype.property`, you are setting up the default value, which looking up `foo2.property` resolves to, when it doesn't have its own property `property`. Setting up `foo2.property` in the constructor defines `foo2`'s own property. You could call it an instance variable, but really, it's just a hash map key.